# Проблема с TypeScript в React приложении

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Возникает ошибка в файле `serviceWorker.tsx`.

```
export function register(config?: Config) {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
        const publicUrl = new URL(
            (process as { env: { [key: string]: string } }).env.PUBLIC_URL,
            window.location.href
        );
    }
    // ...
}
```

Выдает  ошибку в `process`

> Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.ts(2580)

Не могу понять, что мне нужно сделать.

Answer (score 1):

## как убрать ошибку при компиляции TS?

> ВНИМАНИЕ !
>     Если вы понимаете значение `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'`
>     и зачем весь этот `if`.
>     В противном случае ищите обучающую статью
>     и прикладывайте к вопросу ссылку на неё.

### вариант один

использовать `// @ts-ignore`
[typescriptlang.org/docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments)

### вариант другой

`declare var process: any`

### или так

всё же последовать совету из сообщения об ошибке, да установить `@types/node`